# missing output from foreach

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

If I create a simple model, foreach returns every result the way that I think it should:

```
m=function(i,j){data.frame(i=i,j=j)}
> foreach(i=1:2, .combine='rbind') %:% foreach(j=1:2, .combine='rbind') %dopar%{
+ m(i,j)
+ }
  i j
1 1 1
2 1 2
3 2 1
4 2 2
```

but using a more complicated function misses the first loop:

```
# Loop through the prediction model (in parallel) with different parameters
results = foreach(i=1:2, .combine='rbind') %:% foreach(j=1:2, .combine='rbind') %dopar%{
    model(i,j)
}
> results
  i j tpr       fpr       rj                      day
1 1 2   0 0.2127812 1.022387 Wed Oct 29 11:53:45 2014
2 2 1   0 0.2161888 1.023102 Wed Oct 29 11:54:41 2014
3 2 2   0 0.2127812 1.022387 Wed Oct 29 11:53:45 2014
```

You might assume that the function is generating an error when i=1,j=1, but running the function outside the foreach loop gives a good result:

```
> model(1,1)
  i j tpr       fpr       rj                      day
1 1 1   0 0.2161888 1.023102 Wed Oct 29 12:30:31 2014
```

So I assume that I've set up the foreach iterators wrong. Hopefully the problem is more obvious to you than me.

edit:
It also works if %dopar% is replaced with %do%. Of course, this solution defeats the purpose of using foreach.

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would be nice to help you debug. Without it, and without knowing how `model(i,j)` is defined, it's hard to say what the problem is.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the problem with generic data. And, in fact, reconnecting to the server appears to have fixed the problem. (Although it may reappear in the future.) I suspect there was an out-of-memory error, although it wasn't obvious from the verbose output.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your example without model, but maybe you want to write `results = foreach(i=1:2, .combine='rbind') %:% foreach(j=1:2')` i.e. without the second combine argument?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that "model" was returning a different result when executed by a worker, possibly because the worker wasn't initialized correctly.

To test that theory, I would add some additional test code:

```
results <-
  foreach(i=1:2, .combine='rbind') %:%
    foreach(j=1:2, .combine='rbind') %dopar% {
      x <- model(i,j)
      stopifnot(! is.null(x))
      stopifnot(nrow(x) == 1)
      x
    }
```

If "model" always returns a good value, then your theory may be correct, although it's hard to imagine how "model" could cause a problem with the iteration variables.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This time, both i=1 results are omitted. I will have to do some more reading on how to interpret this.